# How to get the IP of the computer, of searches in my google account?

Tags: linux, internet, dns, ip, domain

How do I get the IP of the computer that made researches in my google account, which was

recorded in history that is accessed through my google account?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi, this question is off topic here, since it is about webapps, please read our [FAQ]. If you want to ask it elsewhere, remember to include some more information such as what you're talking about (what exactly to you mean by searches in your google account), mention what you know about the computer (normally you know the IP, what is it you see in this "history") etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the IP of my searches on google?](http://superuser.com/questions/616702/how-to-find-the-ip-of-my-searches-on-google)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you sign in on your Gmail accaunt, in the bottom right corner of the screen, click on "Details".

These are your activities on your account and contain:

1. Access Type (Browser, mobile, POP3, etc.),
2. Location (IP address),
3. Date/Time.